# Is there software to group similar parts of a text file while keeping the original location associated?

Tags: database, text-editor, clustering

This probably doesn't exist, but maybe? When dealing with a corpus of text, sometimes it is useful to organize its parts manually or automatically by topics. These could then be visually grouped together.

One solution with this could be to group its contents visually into folders, text parts etc. So that you could get an overview of each content, but could eventually retrace it back to its source. For example this could be done in a software, where whenever you move text within the file (or arrange them in a file linked to it), it will remember its original locus.

Does anyone have recommendations on what software to use for this? Best case would be if it would be fairly easy to use for people with only basic computer experience.